# Best way to add row to HTML table without re-rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using websockets (socket.io) for real-time stuff, and it may be that a new item is added to a collection which I would like to then add to the screen. Is there a good way to add a row to an HTML table without re-rendering the whole view?

Comment: [HTMLTableElement.insertRow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)

Comment: In jQuery, use `$("#tableID").append(row)`.

Comment: See this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+add+row+to+table

Comment: Hi Alex, if you feel like your question was answered fully, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted. If not, please elaborate so we can further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insertRow` on that table. Here is an example:

```
<table id="TableA">
<tr>
<td>Old top row</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

function addRow(tableID) {
  // Get a reference to the table
  var tableRef = document.getElementById(tableID);

  // Insert a row in the table at row index 0
  var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(0);

  // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
  var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);

  // Append a text node to the cell
  var newText  = document.createTextNode('New top row');
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}

// Call addRow() with the ID of a table
addRow('TableA');

</script>
```

Example taken from the [Mozilla page for insertRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow).